# Not able to add dynamic script and style tag on dynamically create html and iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

I have a string which comes from external source. Now i want to integrate this script and style tag in my application and execute scipt.

```
  const styleScriptText = '<style type="text/css">#checkoutmodal .checkoutmodal-box{background:#FFF !important}</style><script src="https://someurl/lib/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { console.log("test")});</script>'
```

To achieve this i created a dynamic html and appended it in iframe

```
 const html = `<html>
        <head>
       ${styleScriptText}
        </head>
          <body>
          
         
          </body>
    </html>`;
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Now the problem is when i inspect this iframe i am not getting script and style tags please find attached

[image]

I am not sure what mistake i am doing any help is highly appreciated.

**Edit**: Alternative to this is there any way we can **styleScriptText** in application and execute script functions ?

Comment: double click on your source it is there but browsers have limits on how many chars they display in the attribute value

Comment: @EugenSunic  its not there even after doing edit as html i am only getting <style type="text/css"></style>

Comment: but it won't be there it will be in src since you placed it there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting your html into the src attribute of the iframe instead of the iframe content

```
const styleScriptText = '<style type="text/css">#checkoutmodal .checkoutmodal-box{background:#FFF !important}</style><script src="https://someurl/lib/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { console.log("test")});</script>'
```

Define html and set the sourxe

```
const html = `<html>
        <head>
       ${styleScriptText}
        </head>
          <body>
          
         
          </body>
    </html>`;
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
```

Set the iframe content

```
var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(html);
doc.close();
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```